# Export multiple gridviews to 1 excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export

I cannot figure out how to export multiple GridViews to excel. This code only exports 1 GridView and I have 10 of them. GridViews should be separated with an empty row. Ideally, I would like to place those GridViews on the same Excel Sheet. Thanks for looking into this.

```
  protected void ExportExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
    foreach(TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
    }
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int i=0; i<row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }
   }
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView.xlsx");
        using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
            MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Export the source data instead of the GridView data, that way you can keep the correct data types instead of all strings.

Comment: VDWWD, how do you do that with multiple gridviewS?

Comment: Either merge the source data, append the data to the current ExcelWorksheet or create a new ExcelWorksheet for every datasource.

Comment: Can you please show me how you do that? I am having difficulties with with c#. =(

Comment: Sure, but for that I need to know how you are filling your GridViews

Comment: I am filling out the GridViews from the ASP side of the code using SQLDataSource. There is no code behind that I use for that purpose.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8223/filling-the-document-with-data/26423/fill-with-a-datatable-from-an-sql-query-or-stored-procedure#t=201701271404329368718). It shows you how to fill a Excel with data from a Query or Stored Procedure. You only have to create a loop with the correct queries.

Comment: There is only 1 gridview in that example. I am trying to figure out how to export multiple gridviews into a single excel sheet.

Comment: Yes there is, you just have to repeat the `worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);` line several times for each DataTable. And instead of `A1`, the next one should be `A + DataTable.Rows.Count`